# Matlab - how to plot step function

Tags: matlab, plot

I am having a hard time plotting a step function.  The function involves is the Haar scaling function which is defind as:

```
ø(x) = 1 if 0 ≤ x < 1
ø(x) = 0 otherwise
```

I am supposed to plot the following function:

```
f(x) = 2ø(4x) + 2ø(4x - 1) + ø(4x - 2) - ø(4x - 3)
```

This is supposed to give me a plot where f = 2 on the interval 0 ≤ x < 0.5; f = 1 on the interval 0.5 ≤ x < 0.75; f = -1 on the interval 0.75 ≤ x < 1, and f = zero otherwise.

I tried the following code:

```
f = @(t) 2*(4*t > 0) + 2*(4*t > 1) + (4*t > 2) - (4*t > 3);
t = linspace(-2,2,100);
stairs(t,f(t))
```

However, this does not give me an accurate graph.  So what am I doing wrong here?  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean by "not an accurate graph"? in what sense?

Comment: The plot gives me the value f = 2 on 0 < t < 0.25; 4 on 0.25 < t < 0.5; 5 on 0.5 < t < 0.75; and 4 on 0.75 < t < 1.  So it seems like every single term is added to the next one, without "resetting" the graph to zero at t = 0.25, 0.5 and 0.75.

Comment: there is a discrepancy between your definition of "step function" and what a step function is. Usually a step function is f(x) = 1 for x > 0, and zero otherwise. Your definition added a "set-to-zero" for x>1. Your `f(t)` matches the intuitive definition, not your definition.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Do you have any ideas how I can make this work.  I tried: f = @(t) 2*(0 < 4*t < 1) + 2*(1 < 4*t < 2) + (2 < 4*t < 3) - (3 < 4*t < 4), but this basically only gives me a vertical line through t = 0.

Comment: You can't specify inequality ranges like `0 < 4*t < 1` in Matlab, since it will evaluate `0<4*t` first, and then apply the answer to that (0 or 1) to the `< 1` part. You would need to write it as: `0 < 4*t & 4*t < 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be:

```
f = @(t) 2*(4*t > 0 & 4*t < 1) + 2*(4*t > 1 & 4*t < 2) + (4*t > 2 & 4*t < 3) - (4*t > 3);
```

Because every segment should be defined precisely with start and end values.

Answer (score 4):

Your implementation of f only deals with half of your specification of phi.

```
f = @(t) 2*(4*t > 0) + 2*(4*t > 1) + (4*t > 2) - (4*t > 3);
```

In each of the terms applies the inequality `0 < X`, rather than `0 <= X`. Also nothing is done about the `X < 1` inequality.

Rather than trying to make a custom version for each term, why not code up your formula directly?

```
phi = @(x) x >= 0 & x < 1;
f = @(x) 2*phi(4*x) + 2*phi(4*x-1) + phi(4*x - 2) - phi(4*x - 3);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.  However, this only gives me a horizontal line through f = 0.

Comment: Oops, typo. I had `phi = @(x) x>=0 & x< 0;`. This is now fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I wish I could choose this as an accepted answer too, but since I already marked faith_k's answer, and they both work, I hope that's OK.  I really appreciate your help!